# eps image not identical to original after compiling

Tags: graphics, compiling, eps, gnuplot

I have created an eps image with gnuplot (terminal postscript enhanced eps), that is just what I wanted
[image: Original image]

But when I put this image in a tex document and compile a pdf with `latex` `dvips` and`ps2pdf`, I get an image different from the original (as you can see the label for the vertical axes does not correspond to the original image)

[image: image latex ps2pdf]

Finally if I compile a pdf with `latex` and `dvipdfmx`, I get an image identic to the original but the position of the plot and legends are completely crazy

[image: image latex dvi2pdf]

Does anyone understand what happened and can explain me what to do to have everything alright in latex? (if possible by using `latex` `dvips` and`ps2pdf` to compile)

Comment: As this is an issue with the conversion of the EPS file by the driver(s) we are going to need to be able to examine the figure itself to help. Can you make it available somewhere for download? It would also be useful to know how it is being generated.

Comment: You mean that you want the gnuplot script?

Comment: I'd missed the '`gnuplot`' part in the question, so that clears up the 'how it is being generated' part. However, we still need the `.eps` file itself (not the `gnuplot` source: many of us do not have `gnuplot` available).

Comment: Here is the link for the image http://heberg-fichiers.informatique13.com/uploads/2ae079fb4a.eps